# EGA proof verification: universally schematically dominant morphisms and induced morphisms on fibers

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading EGA IV.3, Theorem 11.9.16 about universally schematically dominant morphisms, which states the following. The meaning of schematic dominance is at the end of this post.

> Let $X$ be a locally Noetherian $S$-scheme, $f_{\lambda}\colon Z_{\lambda}\to X$ morphisms, $\mathscr{F}$ a coherent $O_X$ module, $\mathscr{G}_{\lambda}$ quasi-coherent $O_{Z_{\lambda}}$ modules flat over $S$, and $u_{\lambda}\colon\mathscr{F}\to (f_{\lambda})_*\mathscr{G}_{\lambda}$ morphisms. For all $s \in S$, let $i\colon X_s\to X$ and $j_{\lambda}\colon (Z_{\lambda})_s\to Z_{\lambda}$ be the inclusion of fibers, and $(u_{\lambda})_s\colon i^*\mathscr{F}\to (f_{\lambda}\times _S \operatorname{Spec} k(s))_*j^*\mathscr{G}_{\lambda}$ be the "fiber" of $u_{\lambda}$ composed with a base change map. In these settings, the index $\lambda$ runs through the same set $L$.
>
> Then, $(u_{\lambda})_{\lambda}$ is universally schematically dominant w.r.t. $S$ iff for all $s \in S$, $((u_{\lambda})_s)_{\lambda}$ is schematically dominant.

The Only if part is clear. For the if part, first the proof tries to show that schematic dominance instead of universal one. We may assume $S = \operatorname{Spec} A$, and $X = \operatorname{Spec} B$ are affine, and $f_{\lambda}$ are identity, and when $\mathscr{F} = \tilde{M}$ and $\mathscr{G}_{\lambda} = \tilde{N_{\lambda}}$, want to show for $t\in M$ that $t = 0$ if for all $\lambda$, $u_{\lambda}(t) = 0$. (This part is EGA IV.3, 11.9.3, etc.)

Then, because $t = 0$ iff for all maximal ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of B, $t_{\mathfrak{p}} = 0$ where $t_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is the image of $t$ in $M_{\mathfrak{p}}$, the proof says that we may assume that $B$ is local by base changes via $B\to B_{\mathfrak{p}}$. I do not understand this part as schematic dominance of $((u_{\lambda})_s)_{\lambda}$ might not be preserved. Thank you for any kinds of advices and comments in advance.

**Notes on definitions**

In this post, schemes mean usual ones, which are called preschemes in EGA.

In the above setting, $(u_{\lambda})_{\lambda}$ is schematically dominant if for all open subset $U\subseteq X$ and $t\in\mathscr{F}(U)$ with $u_{\lambda}(t) = 0$ for all $\lambda$, $t = 0$. $(u_{\lambda})_{\lambda}$ is universally schematically dominant w.r.t. $S$ if for all $S$-scheme $S'$, the base change of $(u_{\lambda})_{\lambda}$ via $S'\to S$, obtained in the same way as $((u_{\lambda})_s)_{\lambda}$, is schematically dominant.

EGA IV.3 is available [here](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Eleila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/pubtexts.php), for example.

Comment: I've improved your formatting by using \operatorname{Spec} to format $\operatorname{Spec}$, which produces better spacing.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will try to remember that tip.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got an easy answer that the schematic dominance for fibers is preserved when substituting $B_\mathfrak{p}$ for $B$. For all $f,f'\in B$ and the image $\mathfrak{q}\in\operatorname{Spec}$ of $\mathfrak{p}$,
$$
\bigcap_{\lambda} \ker\left(M_{ff'}\otimes_A A_{\mathfrak{q}}/\mathfrak{q}A_{\mathfrak{q}}\to (N_{\lambda})_{ff'}\otimes_A A_{\mathfrak{q}}/\mathfrak{q}A_{\mathfrak{q}}\right) = 0
$$
by definition. Here, take the filtrant inductive limit of this equation over $f\in B\backslash\mathfrak{p}$ to get the desired result.